# Absolute Positioning like an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, positioning, css-position

I have a page that is basically this:

```
<div id="thelist" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#thelist').load('other.aspx', function () { });
</script>
```

the problem that I'm running into is that other.aspx has a lot of controls on it that contain absolute positioning, which I was to be absolute, but with respect to the div and not to the page.  The controls are generated dynamically so they may be added in a different order than they will appear on the screen.  Iframes are out of the question because the iPad does not allow you to scroll iframes.  Basically what I need is a way to anchor the absolute positioning to the div instead of the entire page.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you make a surrounding `<div>` element have "position: relative" then absolutely-positioned elements inside it will have their positions calculated relative to that box.  I don't know for sure about iPad however.

Comment: That worked, you should put it as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give a containing element "position: relative", then absolutely-positioned elements inside it use that container as the reference point.  So, inside it the position "top: 0; left: 0" is the upper left corner of the container, not the whole window.